# Where can I download JDK without installation Ubuntu 9.10?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I have Ubuntu 9.10, and Im not a root. This server contains JDK, but I need some updates (change local policy), and its easy for me to use package Java. E.g. on Windows I downloaded jdk1.6.0_05, set JAVA_HOME, and didn`t have any problems.

Is it possible to download full JDK to my home directory, export $JAVA_HOME without any installation manipulation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can download the JDK from [here](https://cds.sun.com/is-bin/INTERSHOP.enfinity/WFS/CDS-CDS_Developer-Site/en_US/-/USD/ViewProductDetail-Start?ProductRef=jdk-6u22-oth-JPR@CDS-CDS_Developer). If you are able to modify the server's environment, you can try to modify the $JAVA_HOME. If your server is running with lower privileges under another user, you have to do this with this user.

Comment: thanx, I was doing the same (as everione recomended), but something was wrong with bin/java. Ive redownloaded package, and all OK.

Answer (score 2):

Download the jdk Linux "bin" version from Oracle's web site. Wherever directory you run the shell script, it will install the jdk. Very similar to unpacking a .tar.gz.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html

Update your JAVA_HOME and PATH, etc, and you should be good to go!

Comment: thanx, I was doing the same (as everione recomended), but something was wrong with bin/java. Ive redownloaded package, and all OK.

Answer (score 1):

Download the java .deb package and unpack it with

```
dpkg -x <deb> .
```

You will get a `/usr` dir with subdirs and java distribution.

Copy it to wherever you like and set JAVA_HOME.